I keep receiving an error for an invalid hook call not sure what to do
I am working on an API project using React-Router-DOM for navigation and when the initial search results are called I have an array of 8 movies that are shown based on a keyword from the user's search query. Once the user has chosen the specific movie they are looking for by clicking the "SEE MORE" button attached to the movie card it is supposed to redirect to another page that shows specific details about the selected movie, but instead I keep getting uncaught runtime errors that is saying I have an invalid hook call but I'm not sure where I went wrong.

Below is the code that is first used after the original search query :
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Nav from "../ui/Nav";
import { Navigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const API_URL = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=cca6a59";

function Movies() {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const params = useParams();
  const title = params.id;
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  async function onSearch() {
    await fetchMovies();

    Navigate(`/moviecard/${movies}`);

    fetchMovies(movies)
  }

  async function fetchMovies(title) {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`${API_URL}&s=${title}`);
    setMovies(data.Search);
    setLoading(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMovies(title);
  }, [title]);

  return (
    <>
      <Nav />
      <div className="movie__row">
        <div className="movie__wrapper">
          {loading
            ? new Array(8).fill(0).map((_, index) => (
                <div className="movie" key={index}>
                  <div className="movie__img--skeleton">
                    <div className="movie__title--skeleton">
                      <div className="movie__year--skeleton"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))
            : movies.map((movie) => (
                <div className="movie" key={movie.id}>
                  <div className="movie__img">
                    <img src={`${movie.Poster}`} alt="poster" />
                    <div className="movie__content">
                      <h1>{movie.Title}</h1>
                      <h1>{movie.Year}</h1>
                      <p onClick={() => onSearch()}>SEE MORE</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Movies;

This is the code after the user selects "SEE MORE" after selecting the specific movie:
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Nav from "../ui/Nav";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const API_URL = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=cca6a59";

function Moviecard() {
  const params = useParams();
  const imdbID = params.id;
  const [desc, setDesc] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  async function fecthDesc() {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`${API_URL}&i=${imdbID}`);
    setDesc(data.Search);
    setLoading(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fecthDesc();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Nav />

      {loading
        ? new Array(1).fill(0).map((_, movie) => (
            <div className="movie__img--wrapper">
              <h1>${movie.Title}</h1>
              <img src={`${movie.Poster}`} alt="" />
            </div>
          ))
        : desc.map((movie) => (
            <div className="movie__info--wrapper" key={imdbID}>
              <h3>
                <span className="red">Released: </span>${movie.Released}
              </h3>
              <h3>
                <span className="red">Actors: </span>${movie.Actors}
              </h3>
              <h3>
                <span className="red">Genre: </span>${movie.Genre}
              </h3>
              <h3>
                <span className="red">Director: </span>${movie.Director}
              </h3>
              <h3>
                <span className="red">Writer: </span>${movie.Writer}
              </h3>
              <h3>
                <span className="red">Language: </span>${movie.Language}
              </h3>
              <h3>
                <span className="red">Plot: </span>${movie.Plot}
              </h3>
            </div>
          ))}
    </>
  );
}

export default Moviecard;

I'm sure it is something small that I'm just forgetting but I don't know how to attack this problem.

GitHub link to the project is https://github.com/NCOBBagg/fes-final-project/tree/main

Can you include the error message you are getting?

The code is directly calling, e.g invoking, the Navigate component instead of passing it as JSX to be rendered by React. This isn't what you want to do here though.

Import the useNavigate hook from React-Router-DOM and issue an imperative navigation action.
Pass the currently mapped movie id or unique identifier to the search callback to handle issuing the navigation action to the appropriate route path.
Remove the fetchMovies call from the callback, the movies were already fetched when the component mounted.

Example:
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function Movies() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { id: title } = useParams();

  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  function onSearch(movieId) {
    navigate(`/moviecard/${movieId}`);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchMovies(title) {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(`${API_URL}&s=${title}`);
        setMovies(data.Search);
      } catch(error) {
        // catch and handle/ignore
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }

    fetchMovies(title);
  }, [title]);

  return (
    <>
      <Nav />
      <div className="movie__row">
        <div className="movie__wrapper">
          {loading
            ? new Array(8).fill(0).map((_, index) => (
                <div className="movie" key={index}>
                  <div className="movie__img--skeleton">
                    <div className="movie__title--skeleton">
                      <div className="movie__year--skeleton"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))
            : movies.map((movie) => (
                <div className="movie" key={movie.imdbID}>
                  <div className="movie__img">
                    <img src={`${movie.Poster}`} alt="poster" />
                    <div className="movie__content">
                      <h1>{movie.Title}</h1>
                      <h1>{movie.Year}</h1>
                      <p onClick={() => onSearch(movie.imdbID)}>SEE MORE</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}


thank you, I've tried  the changes from your example and now for the component page for the "moviecard" it is complaining that "map" is undefined somehow when it wasn't before.

@CamWatkins I suppose that depends on what your API call returns and what the desc state is updated to. For a single movie's details I wouldn't expect an array to be involved to be mapped. I'll take a look at the APIs to see if I can tell what is returned.

@CamWatkins It looks like the first API call returns movie data with an imdbID property that should be used in the second API call to get specific details. It also looks like the second API call returns an object, so the desc state will be the movie details. Instead of desc.map just reference desc.Released, etc when rendering the single object.

thank you I figured it out I didn't need to map it I was using the wrong term instead of movie for my dynamic categories I needed to add my "desc" to the categories and fix my routes to reflect the right imdbID's
